# Tableview split Swift 2

Tags: uitableview, swift2

Is it possible to have a split table view or do I have to insert a button this large next to each other. 
I have tried playing around with this but no luck. I can only get 2 table views which don’t move at the same time. 
  e.g

[image]

Comment: You can try using UICollectionView insted of UITableView.

Comment: Another option would be to use a scroll view delegate to synchronize movement.

Comment: Once nice advantage to a UICollectionView for this setup is if you decide to support rotation (Portrait/Landscape) it will easily reconfigure (3 wide for example) and give you nice transition animation for free :-]